# Как найти и подсветить слово в таблице google?

Tags: парсер, google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Как найти какое-то конкретное слово в таблице google и подсветить ячейку с ним, с помощью google script?

Answer (score 0):

Конечно можно. Притом и не только Google Apps Script. Возможно так же [УСЛОВНЫМ ФОРМАТИРОВАНИЕМ](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=ru)

Однако, если просто Google Apps Script, то будет что-то такое:

```
function selectText(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() // SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("ССЫЛКА НА ТАБЛИЦУ")
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet() // ss.getSheetByName("ИМЯ ЛИСТА")

  var text = "ВАШ ТЕКСТ" // Текст, который вы хотите найти
  var arrData = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues() // sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn())

  for(var row = 0; row < arrData.length; row++){
    for(var col = 0; col < arrData[0].length; col++){
      if(arrData[row][col] == text){
        sheet.getRange(row+1, col+1).setBackground("blue")
        return // Если нужно только 1 совпадение. Иначе удалите return
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуй, условным форматирование через скрипты было бы лучше всего.

Comment: УФ и через скрипты - зачем?! Или одно, или другое. Зачем лишнее?

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте слова для поиска в dictionary, в переменную range передайте ваш диапазон и запустите функцию substringSearch()

```
let dictionary = {
  stop_words: ["Север", "Мороз", "Друг", "День"],
};

function substringSearch() {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  // range диапазон поиска
  let range = sheet.getRange("A1:G7").getValues();

  range.forEach((item, row) => {
    for (let column = 0; column < item.length; column++) {
      if (typeof item[column] === "string" && item[column] != "") {
        let color = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
          .setForegroundColor("red")
          .build();
        let richText = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(item[column]);
        // item[column] текст ячейки
        dictionary.stop_words.forEach((word) => {
          let arr = searchIndex(
            word.toLocaleLowerCase(),
            item[column].toLocaleLowerCase()
          );
          arr.forEach((ind) => {
            richText.setTextStyle(ind.startIndex, ind.endIndex, color);
          });
          sheet
            .getRange(row + 1, column + 1)
            .setRichTextValue(richText.build());
        });
      }
    }
  });
}

function find(i, subStr, str) {
  // Алгоритм Кнута-Морриса-Пратта (КМП)
  // i-с какого места строки  ищем
  // j-с какого места образца ищем
  for (i; str[i]; ++i) {
    for (j = 0; ; ++j) {
      if (!subStr[j]) return i; // образец найден
      if (str[i + j] != subStr[j]) break;
    }
    // пока не найден, продолжим внешний цикл
  }
  // образца нет
  return -1;
}

function searchIndex(word, text) {
  let res = [];
  let startIndex = 0;

  while (find(startIndex, word, text) !== -1) {
    let poisk = find(startIndex, word, text);
    let endIndex = poisk + word.length;

    if (res.length === 0) {
      res.push({
        startIndex: poisk,
        endIndex: endIndex,
      });
    }
    if (res[res.length - 1].startIndex !== poisk) {
      res.push({
        startIndex: poisk,
        endIndex: endIndex,
      });
    }
    startIndex++;
  }
  return res;
}
```